# Sorting SQL query with the submitting of a form

Tags: php, sql

I have a general understanding of what I would like to do but not sure how to write the SQL.

Users have the ability from changing the sort from ASC to DESC and increase the query limit from 5 to 10.

```
$result=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = 3 ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT $start_from, 5");
```

the option box for asc/desc will end up being $sort_order 
the option box for limit will be $limita

I tried to write it like

```
$result = "SELECT * FROM wp_pod_tbl_bars WHERE status = 3";
 if(!empty($limita)){$result.="LIMIT $limita, 5";}
 if ($result = $mysqli->query($result)) { 
 while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
```

but the query ended up empty due to the query being split into different lines.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? ill post more code if needed but this is generally where my issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put space between `status` and `LIMIT`.

```
$result = "SELECT * FROM wp_pod_tbl_bars WHERE status = 3";
 if(!empty($limita)){$result.=" LIMIT '".$limita."', 5";}
                ---------------^
```

Comment: Wow that little space makes all the difference thanks! Have to wait 10 minutes to accept it as the answer. But I will!

Comment: Yes, I can't believe that space is what stopped it.